# when running the program found a problem in the method_channel_firebase.dart file, how to handle it?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-method-channel

When I run my application suddenly this problem appears **=>**

> Exception has occurred.
> FirebaseException ([core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has
> been created - call Firebase.initializeApp())

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlZ6G.png)

I have tried several things and still get the error. hopefully, there is a solution.

Comment: Please provide your tried code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you have not initialized your app with Firebase.

In the `main` method of your application add this

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

**like this**

[image]